# ipfs daemon: Gateway (readonly) server listening on

Tags: ipfs

I'm not quite sure whether this is the right forum to ask this question.

If I start the ipfs daemon it starts in read only mode. How can I start it in read and write mode?

API server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001
Gateway (readonly) server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080
Daemon is ready

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this in the end? :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `--writable` flag to `ipfs daemon`.

You can see docs for this in `ipfs daemon --help`

Answer (score 1):

To enable writing objects with POST, PUT and DELETE, start the daemon with the writable flag:

```
ipfs daemon --writable=true
```